# Adding mix blend mode makes wordpress admin bar vanish

Tags: css, wordpress

Whenever I add `mix-blend-mode: difference;` to any heading in WordPress it makes the wordpress admin bar at the top dissapear.

Any ideas how to stop it from vanishing when using `mix-blend-mode: difference;` ?

Even when using the built in default wordpress themes it does this so its not my theme causing the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show what CSS selector you are using?

Comment: Just H1 or H2 etc, seems to make it vanish if i add it to any of them.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because I guess it isn't entirely clear what your problem is. You really need to share code or otherwise demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having is [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=503638) chrome bug. Currently the workaround is to put either `transform: translateZ(0);` or `will-change: opacity;` on the parent of the element using `mix-blend-mode`.